# How to Push Rows with Unique Values of Array into Another Array without Changing Order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I am trying to figure out how to push rows of array values from a multidimensional array into another array that has rows of unique values that don't repeat.

For example, if I have an array:

```
[['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','F','G'],['1','2','3','4']]
```

I want to push the rows into another array so that it contains only the rows with values that don't repeat so I will have:

```
[['A','B','C','D'],['1','2','3','4']]
```

This is a simple example.  My array is much larger.  I am trying to do this using javascript for arrays with thousands of rows.

Comment: wait, 2nd subarray is also unique. isnt it?

Comment: So was `['E','F','F','G']` removed because it contains two `'F'`s?

Comment: Yes.  I am trying to push the rows of the array with unique values into another array.  So the the row with two 'F' s would not be pushed into the filtered array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). The Set will remove any duplicate items, so, if the size of the Set equals the size of the row then no elements were removed, which means you can keep the array in the resulting array by returning true from your `.filter()` callback.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','F','G'],['1','2','3','4']];

const res = arr.filter(row => new Set(row).size === row.length);
console.log(res);
```

If you must use `.push()`, this can be done using a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and only pushing the row into your new array when all values are unique:

```js
const arr = [['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','F','G'],['1','2','3','4']];

const newArr = [];
for(const row of arr) {
  if(new Set(row).size === row.length)
    newArr.push(row);
}
console.log(newArr);
```